# Where can I find ALL of the memory specs for the Mac Pro?

Tags: memory, mac-pro

I have a Mac Pro (Mid 2012) with stock RAM, and I'm aware of the usual info about what it's using, e.g. DDR3 1333 PC3-10600E SDRAM, but I want to know more. I understand there are specs such as voltage, timing, bandwidth, rank, registration, and chip configurations.

Where can I find this info for the RAM I currently have instlaled in my machine? Is there some kind of software utility for it? Something I can decipher off of the RAM sticker?

Answer (score 1):

Aha! A quick google search with the alpha-numeric code on the sticker of my RAM led me to the manufacturer's (SK hynix) website, where they have complete details on this particular make of RAM.

https://www.skhynix.com/products/computing/view.jsp?info.ramKind=20&info.serialNo=HMT325U7CFR8C

However, I still wonder if there is software that could have told me all this information.